# xcodebuild linker assertion failure

Tags: ios, xcode, ld, bitcode

I run into this ld assertion error while building an iOS dynamic framework in command line using xcodebuild.

---

```
0  0x10163b342  __assert_rtn + 144
1  0x101678a3a  archive::File<arm64>::makeObjectFileForMember(archive::File<arm64>::Entry const*) const + 1138
2  0x1016783e8  archive::File<arm64>::justInTimeforEachAtom(char const*, ld::File::AtomHandler&) const + 122
3  0x10168ea75  ld::tool::InputFiles::searchLibraries(char const*, bool, bool, bool, ld::File::AtomHandler&) const + 265
4  0x101697db8  ld::tool::Resolver::resolveUndefines() + 160
5  0x10169a117  ld::tool::Resolver::resolve() + 79
6  0x10163c060  main + 812
7  0x7fff9dd4c5ad  start + 1
A linker snapshot was created at:
/tmp/MyKit-2016-02-31-154836.ld-snapshot
ld: Assertion failed: (memberIndex != 0), function makeObjectFileForMember, file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/ld64/ld64-253.9/src/ld/parsers/archive_file.cpp, line 355.
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

---

According to archive_file.cpp source code (http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/ld64/ld64-253.3/src/ld/parsers/archive_file.cpp) it seems there are some kind of symbol corruption while ld is loading a library. But other than that I have no clue how this issue might be fixed.

This issue shows up only when I try to build my framework with bitcode enabled by adding "-fembed-bitcode" compiler flag.

Also, in my ld command, I am trying to link against a few static libraries, one of them is > 4.25 GB (with bitcode built-in), and this size exceeds an unsigned 32-bit integer's max value (~ 3.99 GB). I previously run into a few issue with libtool related to not being able to handle large binary libs, so this is one of my suspicion.

I wonder if anyone has seen similar problems or figure out how to fix it ? Thanks

a few related questions

[Weird xCode linker error I've never seen before saying "Assertion failed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26579615/weird-xcode-linker-error-ive-never-seen-before-saying-assertion-failed)

https://github.com/SciRuby/nmatrix/issues/69

http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2013-October/066722.html

https://github.com/TrinityCore/TrinityCore/issues/14689

https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57438

Comment: 4.25 GB static library?!? :o

Answer (score 6):

Do you want to read the explanation for your error, which is `ld: Assertion failed: (memberIndex != 0) ...`? [Follow this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26579615/weird-xcode-linker-error-ive-never-seen-before-saying-assertion-failed)

Also, don't worry about the size of your static library. The linker will remove all unnecessary information in the final executable. Please read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332063/why-is-my-static-library-so-huge)

TL; DR version:

1. Clean your project using `Command-Option-Shift-K`. Also, choose `Window > Organizer` and switch to the `Projects` tab. Click the right-arrow to the right of the `Derived Data` folder name, delete `Derived Data` folder, and restart XCode.
2. go to `Build Settings` in your `project's settings` => find `Linking->Other linker flags` => add `-v`. This will show you the exact corrupted file that is causing your error, if it still occurs. If you have the error again, please post the path of the corrupted file here, we can work from there.
3. The reason of your error is because **one of your static library is corrupt**. You can remove your 4.25gb lib and rebuild again to see if this is the problem. It is under your project's `target settings -> build phases -> link binary with libraries`. If the error goes away, that might be it. In this case, care to give the name of the lib?

Comment: thanks. I've tried #1 and #2 and they are giving me the same error. -v doesn't give much additional info either. For #3, linker will complain unresolved symbol error if I remove the static library since the lib is need by other parts of the code while linking the framework.

Comment: what is the library called? Also, `Generate Debug Symbols` in project settings can help you reduce the size of static library when building.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to oasisweng's answer.

Does one of the following help?:

- [Every time I upgrade Xcode, I get linker errors with brew installed GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20004120/every-time-i-upgrade-xcode-i-get-linker-errors-with-brew-installed-gcc)
- Are you reliant on any dependencies that [do not have Bitcode enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30848208/new-warnings-in-ios-9)?
- Similar error reported at the [Unity](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/xcode-build-failed-assertion-failed-memberindex-0-function-makeobjectfileformember.365478/) forum; see last post in thread